# Symfony : Session not saving

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm having a problem with Symfony 2.8 on creating a new session 
app_dev.php :

```
Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/storage/h6/846/806846/tmp/sess_agbrtt7qtl6sbasl7hp72hvfug, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /storage/h6/846/806846/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 420
```

config.yml

```
  handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one more config row.

```
   framework:
       session:
           handler_id: session.handler.native_file
           save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
```

Comment: in config.yml ??

Comment: yes, another point is handler_id and save_path are using same indent level in config.yml.